# Alternatives for evaluating $ \int \frac { 1 } { 5 + 4 \cos x} \ dx $ ??

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

$$
          \int \frac { 1 } { 5 + 4 \cos x} \ dx
$$

$$
\text{The solution given in the book for solving this was to use the identity.}
$$

$$
\cos x = \frac{1 - \tan^2 \frac{x}{2}}{1+ \tan^2 \frac{x}{2}}
$$

*I was wondering if there was any other way for solving this  ?*

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve it using the substitution $x=2\arctan t$ and $\mathrm dx=\frac2{1+t^2}\,\mathrm dt$. This will transform your problem into the computation of a primitive of a rational function.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int\frac{1}{5+4\cos(x)}dx$$
now we can use Weierstrauss substitution:
$$u=\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$
so:
$$dx=\frac{2}{1+u^2}du$$
and $$\cos(x)=\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}$$
now we can transform our integral to:
$$I=\int\frac{1}{5+4\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}}\frac{2}{1+u^2}du=\int\frac{1}{5(1+u^2)+4(1-u^2)}du=\int\frac{1}{9+u^2}du=\frac{1}{9}\int\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{u}{3}\right)^2}du$$
now let:$$u=3\tan(v)$$
$$du=3\sec^2(v)dv$$
so:
$$I=\frac{1}{9}\int3\frac{\sec^2(v)}{1+
\tan^2(v)}dv=\frac{1}{3}\int dv=\frac{v}{3}+C=\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{u}{3}\right)}{3}+C=\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{3}\right)}{3}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Cheating a little,
$$x=2 \cot ^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{3}\right)\implies dx=-\frac{6}{u^2+9}\,du$$
$$\int \frac { dx } { 5 + 4 \cos x} =-\frac 23\int \frac {du}{1+u^2}$$

Comment: is the extra $x$ in second line a mistake?

Comment: @HenryLee. Thanks for pointing the typo !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici But how did you think of that *Substitution* ??

Comment: @JIM. I wrote it : *Cheating !*

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  How Did you cheat ??

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici you just manipulated and used Tangent half angle substitution !!

Comment: @JIM. In fact, the first idea came from $5^2-4^2=3^2$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici But can we manipulate tangent half angle sub. only for this problem or for other problems also ?

Comment: @JIM. The tangent half-angle substitution is a very standard way for many integration problems in which only trigonometric functions are involved. The problem is that you end with "polynomial" expressions and some of them cannot be integrated using elementary functions. But, I suppose that, for the time being, it would be a very, very good way for your problems. Good luck in your studies. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{1}{5+4\cos x}dx=\int\frac{1}{5+4\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}} \ dx= \int\frac{2e^{ix}}{4e^{2ix}+10e^{ix}+4} \ dx $$
let $u = e^{ix}$ and $du = ie^{ix}$
$$\int\frac{-2i}{2u^2+10u+4}\ du = -i\int\frac{1}{(u+\frac{1}{2})(u+2)}du$$
and the rest is easy!

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\displaystyle I =\int\frac{1}{5+4\cos x}dx=\int\frac{5-4\cos x}{25-16\cos^2 x}dx$$

$$ I =5\int\frac{(\tan x)'}{9+16\tan^2 x}dx-4\int\frac{(\sin x)'}{25-16\cos^2 x}dx$$

Comment: I do not understand how did you this from the very second step?